# Login to website not possible with firefox, but with chrome and edge

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firefox, authentication

can somebody help me finding the occuring bug while login process to my [website](http://qsk.qsk.tu-berlin.de/masteranden/login.php). 
As a research assistant one of my tasks is to support students with their final thesis. Therefore i code a little administration to keep things efficient.

For some reason i cant login to my website using firefox (50.0.2). Neither in normal nor in private mode. Firefox mobile does not work too. Chrome and edge are working fine. The login credentials are:

e-mail: test@test.test | pw:test

I also checked the apache error.log, but no error was logged :(

Can somebody help me finding the bug?

Login.html

```
<form class="form-signin">
             <label for="inputEmail" class="">E-Mail</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="" >Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " type="submit" id="button_login">Login</button>
            </form>
```

login (jquery)

```
            $(document).on('click', '#button_login', function () {
            var mail = $('#inputEmail').val()
            var passwort = $('#inputPassword').val()
            var post_objekt = {}
            post_objekt.mail = mail;
            post_objekt.passwort = passwort;
            $.post('ajaxController.php?fId=16', {data: JSON.stringify(post_objekt)}, function (rueck) {
                if (!rueck.trim()) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert(rueck);
                }
            })
        });
```

[Firebug for ajaxCOntroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaMed.png)

Beginning of login.php

```
session_start('masterand');
if (!isset($_SESSION['masterand']['id'])) {
//Session starten
$_SESSION['masterand']['id'] = '0';
}
if ($_SESSION['masterand']['id'] != '0') {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Matthias

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe a point in the right direction: this is most certainly a javascript issue as that is the only reason one browser would fail while others succeed. PHP / MySQL are both server-side and therefore make no difference which client you're using. Might want to update your tags and provide any javascript associated with the login. Firefox console gives me [this message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Insecure_passwords).

Comment: Thx mister martin, but how can i fix this? Is there any bug in th js code?

Comment: I'm also noticing that `ajaxController.php` is not sending any response.

Comment: You have at `head` `script` section that loads `jquery`. Add `type="text/javascript"` to that script tag.

Comment: Thx Evgeny. type was added, but still no login possible.

Comment: hmmm ajaxController.php only respond some text in case of failed login. Otherwise a session object is created.

Comment: @Matthias try adding `action="javascript:;"` to your form.

Comment: Thx it works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Firefox apparently doesn't like your form not having an action attribute. Adding the following should resolve the problem:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="javascript:;">
```